# React Native iOS LaunchScreen is black

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a RN app (v0.66.1) and I have customized my LaunchScreen via XCode. However, the screen is just black. I have checked my *info.plist* and it is set as the launch screen, so I'm not sure what else I need to do to get it to show up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the issue. It's not widely-documented, and you have to search through logs to see it, but my icon was too large for the screen to work. I had to reduce the file to the dimensions that it wanted (1024 x 1024) and it built and showed perfectly.